# MongoDB - How to Update/push the objects in an array which is contained by another object which in turn is contained by another array

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

Here is a code snippet,

```
{
    "summary":[
        {
            "chem_id":"5e18c858c88e1e2328771593",
            "chem_sale": [
                {
                    "product_id": "5e3c5042ac7e0d67c3b5ae6f",
                    "product_sale": 8900
                },
                {
                    "product_id": "5e3c5029ac7e0d67c3b5ae6e",
                    "product_sale": 6500
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "chem_id":"5e1b1cb5f3123a3a74f014f5",
            "chem_sale": [
                {
                    "product_id": "5e3c5042ac7e0d67c3b5ae6f",
                    "product_sale": 2900
                },
                {
                    "product_id": "5e3c5029ac7e0d67c3b5ae6e",
                    "product_sale": 3500
                }
            ]
        }       
    ]
}
```

how to add new product object to chem_sale array if its id is unique and
how to update the product_sale ?

I have tried this to add new product object to summary array

```
 let saleRecord = await saleRecordModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      { emp_id: req.params.id },
      { $addToSet: { summary: req.body.summary } },
      { new: true, upsert: false }
    );
```

I'm using mongoose version 5.9.0
But I'm getting duplicated results. Please help me.

Comment: where does `emp_id` come from? Could you provide a sample of an object from saleRecordModel collection?

Comment: @Jérôme the saleRecord model collection conatins emp_id, (ObjectID) in addition to the summary array as described above

Comment: Ok. And then you want to push a new object in `chem_sale` for a specific `chem_id`? Also, you want to update `product_sale` for a given `product_id` in all entry of summary?

Comment: @Jérôme `product_sale` should be updated if `product_id` matches a given `product_id`  of the `chem_sale` array.

Comment: @Yashwanthsomayajula : It would be easy if you can provide your request & expected output (transformed document)..what is your MongoDB version ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is the `arrayFilters` option. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#update-array-filters

see more example for the identifier `$[<identifier>]`
[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up.*S*[%3Cidentifier%3E]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_[%3Cidentifier%3E])

```
db.saleRecord.update(
    { emp_id: '<EMP_ID>' },
    { $set: {'summary.$[].chem_sale.$[chemSaleElement].product_sale': 1000 }},
    { arrayFilters: [{ 'chemSaleElement.product_id': '5e3c5029ac7e0d67c3b5ae6e' }] }
)
```